# Parse object content

Tags: python, class

I'm trying to parse an error that [Requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) returns when my test server is not started.

```
print("%s\n" % type(error))
<class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'>

print("%s\n" % error)
HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=8080): Max retries exceeded with url: /test_soap (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fecf0892a90>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connexion refusée'))
```

When I open `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages/requests/exceptions.py` I can see the `ConnectionError` class has a `response` and `request` attributes:

```
print("%s\n" % error.response)
None

print("%s\n" % error.request)
<PreparedRequest [POST]>
```

But I would like to access to the `urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection` object so I can print the `Failed to establish a new connection` error message.

How exactly the `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` class is built to show this error message when I print it?

Comment: You could try something like `except requests.exceptions.ConnectionError as e:` and you could look at the [`traceback`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/traceback.html) module.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**TL;DR** You can't.

Not nicely at least.

The good thing is that you shouldn't, or at least you don't need to.

Consider:

```
import requests

try:
    requests.get('http://localhost')
except Exception as error:
    print(error)
    print(type(error))
    print([o for o in dir(error) if not o.startswith('__')])
```

outputs

```
# HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000019F34649C18>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))
# <class 'requests.exceptions.ConnectionError'>
# ['args', 'characters_written', 'errno', 'filename',
#  'filename2', 'request', 'response',
#  'strerror', 'winerror', 'with_traceback']
```

If we look at the last output, nothing really stands out except for `args`:

```
print(error.args)
```

As usual, this will be a tuple that will contain the thrown object:

```
# (MaxRetryError("HTTPConnectionPool(host='localhost', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x00000189C4D7AD30>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it'))"),)
```

From here the way to the underlying `urlib3` exception is ugly and messy, and does not really give us any new info we didn't already know:

```
print(error.args[0].reason.args[0])
# <urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000023476C40390>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it
```

Comment: Thanks it helps. Where do the `args`, `characters_written`, ... come from?

And how python knows what to print with `print(error)`?

Comment: @Adhrill They are attributes of the exception object, and `print(error)` prints the output of `error.__str__()`, as usual.

Comment: `requests.exceptions.ConnectionError` class doesn't have a `__str__` method, so I believe it uses the `__str__` method from the default `exception` object?

Comment: @Adhrill `BaseException.__str__`